# Best way to make a tabs menu in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

We have 4 activities that we wanna be able to switch between with a tabs like menu. but since TabsActivity has been deprecated, it looks like the only way to make this is with actionbars, and converting out activities to fragments? 
Is there an easier way of making tabs, where we can keep our activites as they are now, and not having to restructure alot of stuff to make it work?

Comment: I can see a lot of words, but no question. If you want people to help, please clearly explain the problem. Some paragraphs/code/pictures would help.

Comment: The question is: "How can we most easily modify code that uses TabsActivity to not use a deprecated API?"

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way. But unless your TabsActivity code is woefully complex, you'll probably not find it too painful to convert to FragmentActivity. After all, the hard part is usually in what the Activities do inside anyway.